# MultiSubmitButton Clientside validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, validation

I have created one View. In that i have put 2 Multisubmit buttons for "create" and "cancel".

Now, on cancel click, clientside validation is going to call. but I don't want to call clientside validations.

I have written code as below, please check it. I don't want validations to be executed on cancel button click.

```
@model Blog.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register New User";
}

@using Microsoft.Web.Mvc;
@using MVC3MultiSubmitButtonExtension;
<h2>
    Register New User</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fill User Details</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
        </div>
        <p>
            @*  <input type="submit" value="Create" />*@
           @Html.MultiSubmitButton(Url.Action("Create"), "btnCreate", "Create")
           @Html.MultiSubmitButton(Url.Action("Cancel"), "btnCancel", "Cancel")
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Click here to go Login Page", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assign `class="cancel"` to your cancel submit button, clientside validation won't run. The way you assign this class is not something that I can tell as you seem to be using some custom helper `Html.MultiSubmitButton` which is not part of ASP.NET MVC. So you will have to check its documentation.

Comment: Yes.. It works.. But i want to clear particular htmlvalidator value to be clear for example.. For EmailAddress HTML editor i want to clear text.